# How to create a docker image for Sagemaker that is not part of the amazon estimator to create an endpoint?

Tags: docker, machine-learning, endpoint, amazon-sagemaker

I have built a custom model in Sagemaker and serialized the model through pickle. I want to deploy my model through Sagemaker hosting services and read through this

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/how-it-works-hosting.html

But I am lost on how to build my own Docker container for a custom model with an algorithm that is currently not implemented as part of the Amazon Estimator.

How do I build my own docker image to load into ECR to then build the container that allows me to create an endpoint?

Answer (score 4):

Have the look at this guide: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/master/advanced_functionality/scikit_bring_your_own/container

It shows how to create a Container for both Training Jobs and Endpoint deployment.

If you only need to deploy the Endpoint, you can skip the training part.

As mentioned in the documentation, for a SageMaker Endpoint, you need a Docker container with a web server implemented that listens to HTTP requests at route "/ping" and "/invocations".
In the guide, they have implemented a flask web server using NGINX and Gunicorn.

For your use case:
https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/master/advanced_functionality/scikit_bring_your_own/container/decision_trees

In this directory, you can skip the "train" file and keep rest of the files intact except for the "predictor.py" file. It's the file that you will modify to implement your own inference algorithm.